# unknown attribute 'description' for Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Имеется миграция, в которой необходимо несколько конкретных постов "поправить":

```
Post.transaction do
    Post.all.each do |post|
        post.update_column(:code, post.code.tr(' ', '_'))
    end

    default_user = User.unscoped.first

    first_post = Post.find_by(code: 'some_code')

    if first_post.present?
        first_post.update_columns(
            uuid: FIRST_POST_FIXED_UUID,
            system: true
        )
    else
        new_first_post = Post.create!(
            title: 'Grammar',
            description: 'No description',
            code: 'some_code',
            system: true,
            user: default_user,
            last_user: default_user
        )
        new_first_post.update_column(:uuid, FIRST_POST_FIXED_UUID)
    end

    # ...
end
```

Эта миграция падает с ошибкой:

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'description'
>   for Post.

Поле `description` в таблице `posts` присутствует. В `rails c` если выполнить `Post.all`, то также можно увидеть поле `description`.

Если выполнить `rails db:migrate` второй раз, то все пройдет успешно - никаких ошибок и по итогу все изменения, прописанные в миграции, выполнятся.

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что это, почему оно происходит и как исправить, так как такое в продакшен не очень хочется отправлять?..

**ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ**

Это миграция не одинока. До нее есть еще парочка. И в одной из таких идет переименование одной таблицы в `posts`. Когда дело доходит до миграции, описанной выше, то код `Post.column_names` выдает поля от старой таблицы. А при повторном запуске миграции все нормально, так как судя по всему обновляется кэш AR или что-то подобное. Можно как-то вылечить на месте (внутри миграции)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я писал выше в самом вопросе - дело было в том, что до этой миграции была еще одна, в которой шло переименование таблицы в `posts`. Отсюда возникала проблема, что последующие миграции "не знали" о новых полях (имели старые).

Исправляется при помощи добавления этой строки в начало миграции:

```
Post.reset_column_information
```

Answer (score 2):

> Имеется миграция, в которой необходимо несколько конкретных постов "поправить":

Это бывает, но есть одна осложняющая деталь.

**Не используйте модели в миграциях**. Реализация модели зависит от *актуального* состояния базы данных и по мере эволюции продукта имеет право сломать совместимость с любым из старых состояний.

А на практике миграции могут быть запущены из любого состояния БД. В зависимости от того, насколько далеко отстали пользователи.

Используйте SQL или обёртки, которые не рассчитывают на реализацию в вашем приложении. `ActiveRecord::Base` (и его `transaction`, `find_by_sql`) использовать обычно безопасно, а вот `ApplicationRecord` (базовый класс всех моделей, создаваемый с Rails 5 по умолчанию) уже не очень.

Если ну очень хочется магии AR, можно попробовать создавать анонимные классы (с помощью `Class.new`) в миграциях, которые содержат интересующие вас черты (наследуются от `ActiveRecord::Base`, содержат какие-нибудь скоупы), но после окончания миграции не используются абсолютно нигде.